# Why can't my Arduino handle to make a PWM signal?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I want to control the duty cycle and frequency of the the duty cycle to control an LED.

```cpp
float dutycycle = 1000;//base dutycycle is x microseconds
float duty_on = 500;//on-time in microseconds
float multiplicator = 1;//dutycycle multiplicator to tune the frequency of the signal   
float duty_off = dutycycle - duty_on;      

void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);//bright
  delayMicroseconds(duty_on*multiplicator); //waiting
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);//dark
  delayMicroseconds(duty_off*multiplicator);//waiting
}
```

Right now I think my code means that the LED turns of and on every half millisecond. But I want to use the LED as a stroboscope too (with an on time of 500 ms and an off time of 500 ms for example). Therefore I introduced the multiplicator to my code which should just stretch the the on- and off-time.

The problem is that it doesn't work for this time span and I can not explain myself why. If anyone could help me I would be very pleased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overflow. `delayMicroseconds` can take a maximum value of 16383. [See](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/DelayMicroseconds).

For your longer case (500 ms), I recommend using `delay` instead, which uses milliseconds.